# Sass map margins error

Tags: sass, maps

I'm trying to use a simple map in sass to create margin classes.

```
$margins:(
  "5": 5px,
  "10": 10px,
  "15": 15px,
  "20": 20px,
  "25": 25px,
  "30": 30px
);

@each $margin in $margins{
  .u-mt-#{$margin}{
    width: $margin !important;
  }
}
```

In SassMeister I'm getting the error.

Invalid CSS after ".u-mt-5 ": expected selector, was "5px"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it thanks

```
@each $margin, $margin in $margins{
  .u-mt-#{$margin}{
    width: $margin !important;
  }
}
```